# compare rows with sweep function - how to do it properly?

Tags: r, functional-programming, data-manipulation

just trying to compare the first row of two dataframes using "sweep". Unfortunately the function returns only FALSE, if condition ist met, that x is bigger than y. In case that x equals y, I want the same FALSE output. Unfortunately my attempt is not working and I can't see why. In case x equals y, there is still a TRUE, but there should be a FALSE. Please help:

```
colvec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m")
gap_size_uncut <-  as.data.frame(rbind(c(6,1,5,1,1,1,4,5,26,3,35,23,3)))
NA_Count       <-  as.data.frame(rbind(c(3,6,5,7,1,3,4,6,1,0,1,1,3)))
colnames(gap_size_uncut) <- colvec
colnames(NA_Count) <- colvec

sweep(as.matrix(gap_size_uncut[1,]), 1, as.matrix(NA_Count[1,]),
      FUN = function(x,y) (x <= y ), 
      check.margin = FALSE)
NA_Count
gap_size_uncut
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sweep` with `MARGIN = 2`.

```
sweep(gap_size_uncut[1,], 2, NA_Count[1,], `<=`)

#      a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h     i     j     k     l    m
#1 FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

If the dimensions are the same you can compare the two dataframe directly without `sweep`.

```
gap_size_uncut <= NA_Count

#         a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h     i     j     k     l    m
#[1,] FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Comment: Nice to know! The second solution is a lot more concise. Thanks!